# What is the best way to write an array sorting and filtering function with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, filter

There is a catalog of games in which the list of games passes through several filters.

[image: sort and filter list]

The games are divided by platforms (HTC, PSVR, PS5, Favorites), when you click on the tab, a calculated property is triggered, for PS5 it is showPS5Games, which accepts the selected genre (genre), sorting (selectedSort), checkbox "For children" (isChild), checkbox "For two" (isLocalMultiplayer) and game search by name/tag/genre (query). All parameters can be combined in any way.

Full code of showPS5Games:

```
showPS5Games: state => (
  query,
  genre,
  isChild,
  isLocalMultiplayer,
  selectedSort
) => {
  if (genre == "все" && isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category == "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          isChild &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все" && isChild) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isChild) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isChild &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все" && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (isLocalMultiplayer) {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else if (genre === "все") {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" && game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" && game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  } else {
    var tmpArray = state.games.filter(game => {
      return (
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.genre.includes(query)) ||
        (game.category === "ps5" &&
          game.genre === genre &&
          game.tag.includes(query))
      );
    });
  }
  var filteredGames = [];
  if (selectedSort == "ascending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "descending") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bygenre") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.genre.localeCompare(b.genre));
  } else if (selectedSort == "bytag") {
    filteredGames = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => a.tag.localeCompare(b.tag));
  } else {
    filteredGames = tmpArray;
  }
  return filteredGames;
}
```

I wrote a branched function with many if's for every possible combination, which is not optimized and not aesthetically pleasing. Also, for some reason, filtering of the array by both selected checkboxes does not work, only one works correctly. What is the best way to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of duplicated logic here. The first step to making this more efficient would be cleaning up the if statements. For example you have:

```
if (genre == "все" && isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
...
} else if (isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
```

Some of these conditions can be checked once with a nested if:

```
if (isChild && isLocalMultiplayer) {
    if (genre == "все" {
    ...
    }
}
```

Additionally the returns could be simplified for the same reason. For example, this return

```
      return (
    (game.category == "ps5" &&
      isChild &&
      game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
      game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
    (game.category == "ps5" &&
      isChild &&
      game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
      game.genre.includes(query)) ||
    (game.category == "ps5" &&
      isChild &&
      game.isLocalMultiplayer &&
      game.tag.includes(query))
  );
```

Could be simplified to:

```
 return (
    game.category == "ps5" &&
    isChild &&
    game.isLocalMultiplayer && 
   (game.title.toLowerCase().includes(query) || 
    game.genre.includes(query) ||
    game.tag.includes(query))
);
```

I hope this will help you get to the bottom of the other issues you're seeing here, good luck!